# Building a CONTENT_URI for a custom contract

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Android's documentation provides an example of how to fill a list from a Loader, specifically, from the contacts database.  They use this call:

```
// Called when a new Loader needs to be created
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
}
```

I have written my own custom `PeerDatabaseContract`:

```
public class PeerDatabaseContract {
    private PeerDatabaseContract() {}

    public static abstract class PeerEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "peers";
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI; // Instantiation?

        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PEER_ID = "userid";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PEER_NAME = "name";
    }
}
```

I would like to use this in a similar fashion as the `ContactsContract` and use this in a list.  Assume that my content provider's authority is `com.thirtythreeforty.peerapp.authority`.

How do I define the `CONTENT_URI` so that I can simply construct a `CursorLoader` from it, as in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1: Use `Uri.parse("content://com.thirtythreeforty.peerapp.authority/whatever/else/you/need")`

Option #2: Use a `Uri.Builder` to build a `Uri` from component parts